# Fetching data from json using jsonArrayRequest

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to retrieve json data using JsonArrayRequest.Here's my code for doing that

```
public class QuestionDetailFragment extends Fragment {
   private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/forumtest/readquestion.php?format=json";
   private String data;
   RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_details_layout, container, false);
   readQuestionDetails();
    Log.d("user","data:"+data);
    return view;
}

private void readQuestionDetails() {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {
                    for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        data=jsonObject.getString("user");



                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("user",e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("user", error.getMessage());

        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
}
```

The problem is that when i use data variable inside the loop it returns the required value, but whenever i try to use the data variable outside the loop(let's say when i use data from onCreateView) it returns null value.

Comment: "but whenever i try to use the data variable outside the loop(let's say when i use data from onCreateView)" - how are you using it?

Comment: Log.d("user","data:"+data); from OnCreateView

Comment: I think your readQuestionDetails() method runs on different Thread. May be by the time you call this method Log.d("user","data:"+data), the value of data has not been set. Log.d("user","data:"+data); runs on UI Thread

Comment: im calling readQuestionDetails() before using data, isn't the value of data supposed to be already  set!!

Comment: When two methods run on different threads they might not follow top to bottom execution process. In your case, the data has not been set when it is called.

Comment: You have to print out the data inside  readQuestionDetails() method

Comment: i guess that's the only option i've got. Anyway,thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the JsonArrayRequest is being added to the volley queue which executes task asynchronously. So even though you are calling the `Log.d("tag","data:"+data);` after `readQuestionDetails()` the request has not executed yet, meaning `data` is null.

Something like this will work:

```
public class QuestionDetailFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/forumtest/readquestion.php?format=json";
    private String data;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_details_layout, container, false);
        readQuestionDetails();
        return view;
    }

    private void readQuestionDetails() {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {
                    for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        data=jsonObject.getString("user");
                        printData(data);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("user",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("user", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void printData(String data){
        Log.d("user","data:"+data);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I did the same thing ,a day ago ,with JsonRequestObject and it was working fine.

Comment: Probably due to the request not taking very long to complete so that it was already finished by the time it got to the Logging line, this is known as a race condition. Now the request is taking longer and the request is no longer 'winning' the race

Comment: it works fine when i use it inside the loop, but i need to use it from oncreateView so that i can pass its value to another fragment.

Comment: Anything done inside printData() is the earliest possible moment that you can do anything with the data obtained from the Request

Comment: so there's nothing i can do about it? Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: It just means that you are coming about the problem the wrong way. i.e why do you need to use it inside onCreateView?

Comment: So what is wrong with doing that within `printData()`? or just straight in the `onResponse` callback?

Comment: actually, i need to add the whole data to a list like userlist.add(user) and then pass that list to another fragment. I tried using userlist.add(user) inside printData, but the problem is same.

Comment: you mean passing data directly to another fragment from loop?

Comment: Yes, or creating the fragment inside it. I would also stop refering to it as a `loop` as you will only confuse yourself.

If you did that the fragment would still be created via `onCreateView`